# Python - connect to hive using Pyodbc

Tags: python, hive, pyodbc

I am trying to connect to hive server using `PyODBC` however I am getting error. Not sure how to resolve it.

HiveServer is running on EMR.

**Code**

```py
import pyodbc
cnxnstr = 'Driver={/usr/lib/hive/lib/native/Linux-amd64-64/libhortonworkshiveodbc64.so};' \
          'HiveServerType=2;' \
          'Host=10.164.7.50;' \
          'Port=10001;TransportMode=HTTP;' \
          'UID=gshah03;' \
          'AuthMech=3;' \
          'ThriftTransport=SASL;' \
          'Schema=my_database;' \
           'PWD=mypass$'
cnxn = pyodbc.connect(cnxnstr, autocommit=True)
```

**Error**

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC][Hortonworks][ThriftExtension] (5) Error occurred while contacting server: invalid sasl status. This could be because you are trying to establish a non-SSL connection to a SSL-enabled server. (5) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

I tried adding this option as well, but not working `'sslverify=0; Option=3;'`

**Hive-Site.xml**

```xml
<property>
    <name>hive.server2.enable.doAs</name>
    <value>false</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.port</name>
    <value>10000</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hive.server2.thrift.http.port</name>
    <value>10001</value>
  </property>
```

**Update:**

with `10000` port, I am getting following error:

**Error**

```
Error: ('HY000', '[HY000] [unixODBC][Hortonworks][Hardy] (34) Error from server: connect() failed: Connection refused. (34) (SQLDriverConnect)')
```

Comment: Why not `pyspark` or `impyla` or `pyhive`?

Comment: pyhive does not support over sasl.   PySpark I am able to access however while converting to pandas dataframe I am facing issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62556754/converting-spark-dataframe-to-pandas-dataframe-importerror-pandas-0-19-2-m

Comment: The answer given there is correct.

Comment: It's not working

Comment: Also. There are use case when people wants get data just using Python notebook..

Comment: I understand it's not working, but it's not clear what interpreter your notebooks are using and how you're managing python across your Spark cluster... Okay... The options I listed work in notebooks too. Notebooks don't change how code runs. The interpreter does

Comment: The problem here, I think, is that ODBC doesn't connect to the Thrift port because those are different protocols

Comment: What do you mean could you explain?

Comment: The tools I listed first connect to the `hive.server2.thrift.port` - which is [Apache Thrift](https://thrift.apache.org/). I never have used ODBC with Python or Hive because i don't see the point, because Spark **should** work, **and will be faster**

Answer (score 1):

1. Create odbc driver dsn (Navigate through ODBC data source Administrator 64 bit )under User DSN.
2. Click on Add (select cloudera ODBC driver for Apache Hive, if its not present download the latest one from cloudera site)
   3.Server/Hosts: Your Server Name
   DSN Name and Description: You can give you as per your wish
   Port: Port Number
   Authentication: Username and Password
   Transport: HTTP
   HTTP Path: HTTP path (In HTTP options)      
   Require SSL: Select cacerts.pem(Its present in clouder odbc driver folder-lib) and also check self signed server certificate - Click ok
3. Click on test button , you should see a successful connection

Once the dsn is created , use that dsn in python using pyodbc and build a connection. Using this connection you can query out you hive tabes.